# Code unable to distinguish between perfect and non-perfect numbers in php

Tags: php, html, debugging

I am supposed to write a program that:

1. takes in a positive integer from a html form
2. then in another php script, checks if this integer is a perfect number or not and print the result (result as in if integer is perfect or not).

*A perfect number* is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of all its factors EXCLUDING itself.

**Problem I'm facing**:
The code runs but for every positive number entered, I get the same output which is "Yes, XXX is a perfect number" even when the number isn't.

*Could someone help me find the bug(s) in my code? I can't locate the problems in the code.*

```
#html form

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="lab_2_3.php" method="POST">
        Enter positive integer:
        <input type="number" name="pos_num" min="1"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
#php script

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        $pos_num = $_POST["pos_num"];
        
        function get_factors($pos_num){
            $myarray = array(); //creating new array
            for ($i = 1; $i <= ceil(($pos_num ** 0.5)); $i++){
                if ($pos_num % $i == 0){
                    $myarray[] = $pos_num; //appending array in php
                }
            
            return $myarray; }
        }
        
        function get_total($myarray){
            $total_val = 0;
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($myarray); $j++){
                $total_val += $myarray[$j];
            } return $total_val;
        }

        $a_list = get_factors($pos_num);
        $check_if_perf = get_total($a_list);
        if ($check_if_perf == $pos_num){

            echo "Yes, $pos_num is a perfect number";
        } 
        
        else{
            echo "No, $pos_num is not a perfect number";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing, you push `$pos_num` onto `$myarray[]` so the original input number and not the factors of the number. (in your get_factors function)

Comment: Please format your code. And instead of posting the entire code, try to minimize the code example as much as possible while still showcasing your incorrect behavior.

Comment: debugging tip:  verify that the variables are actually what you think they are.  Check what the value of `$a_list` is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried printing out some variables to see what exactly the function was working with:

```
function get_factors($pos_num){
    $myarray = array(); //creating new array
    $end = $pos_num ** 0.5;
    print "$end\n";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $end; $i++){
        print "$i: " . $pos_num % $i . "\n"; 
        if ($pos_num % $i == 0){
            $myarray[] = $i; //appending array in php
        }
    
    return $myarray; }
}
// ===>
3.1622776601684
1: 0
No, 10 is not a perfect number
```

From this, it was evident the for loop was not functioning as expected.  So step one is to clean up the code and indenting.  The error became obvious:  misplaced end bracket.

```
function get_factors($pos_num)
{
    $myarray = array(); //creating new array
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pos_num ** 0.5; $i++) {
        print "$i: " . $pos_num % $i . "\n"; 
        if ($pos_num % $i == 0){
            $myarray[] = $i; //appending array in php
        }
    }
    
    return $myarray; 
}

// ==>
1: 0
2: 0
3: 1
No, 10 is not a perfect number
```

However, `get_factors()` does not correctly compute the factorials.  The end limit, set by `$pos_num ** 0.5` does not gather all the factorials.  For example,

```
print 6 ** 0.5;

// ==>
2.4494897427832
```

To fix this, we want to get the first half of the factorials (inclusive of n/2)

```
function get_factors($pos_num)
{
    $myarray = array(); //creating new array
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pos_num/2; $i++) {
        if ($pos_num % $i == 0){
            $myarray[] = $i; 
        }
    }

    return $myarray; 
}
```

Now, putting all the code together in a standard format, with notes explaining why (I've also left some of the debugging commented out):

```
<?php
// testing...
// $_GET["pos_num"] = 496;

// always start out with PHP logic, never HTML.  

// Deal with input:
// if submission is not destructive (ie, insert, update, delete), use GET.  
// if submission changes data state, use POST.  POST should always be followed
// with a redirect.  (Post-Redirect-Get pattern)
if(isset($_GET["pos_num"])) {
    $pos_num = $_GET["pos_num"];
    $a_list = get_factors($pos_num);
    $check_if_perf = get_total($a_list);

    $is_perfect = ($check_if_perf == $pos_num); // boolean
}

// functional logic:
function get_factors(int $pos_num) : array
{
    $myarray = array(); //creating new array
    $end = $pos_num /2;
    // $end = $pos_num ** 0.5;
    // print "$end\n";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $end; $i++){
        if ($pos_num % $i == 0){
            $myarray[] = $i; //appending array in php
        }
    }
    return $myarray; 
}

function get_total(array $myarray) : int
{
    $total_val = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($myarray); $j++){
        $total_val += $myarray[$j];
    } 
    return $total_val;
}

// print_r(get_factors($pos_num));
// all done with logic, show presentation:
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php if(isset($_GET["pos_num"])): ?>
    <div>
        <?= $is_perfect 
            ? "Yes, $pos_num is a perfect number"
            : "No, $pos_num is not a perfect number"
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <form action="lab_2_3.php" method="GET">
        Enter positive integer:
        <input type="number" name="pos_num" min="1"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Working example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1e5823075c71272c67e09448e6302a4dffead39

Comment: Thank you for the input! Hm after using the function above, now for every number, I get a "No, XXX is not a perfect number" output even if it is. I tried it with these numbers: 6, 28, 496 (perfect numbers)

Comment: Your formula cuts off the factors too soon.  `6 ** .05 = 2.4494897427832`, however you need the factors to go up to 3.  I'll post a solution with some other hints.

Comment: It just dawned on me that `$pos_num ** 0.5` was a typo.  I was thinking that it was part of some whiz-bang smarter-than-me formula.  smh.  Both of the errors in your code were simply typos.  Let this be a lesson.  It's a pretty good example of real-life programming.  And the only way to solve it is by taking the problem apart, piece by piece, and question every result.  The program does exactly what you say, not what you mean.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using `$end = $pos_num /2;` in `$i <= $end` instead of using `$end = $pos_num ** 0.5` did the trick for me!